# What is the restriction of substitution axiom?

Tags: real-analysis, axioms

In Terence Tao's book "Analysis I" 3rd edtion page 329 he wrote:

"• (Substitution axiom). Given any two objects x and y of the same type, if $x = y$, then $f(x)=f(y) $for all functions or operations $f$."

Here's my question: let $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, and given we know $n^2=4$, then we yield $n=2$ from the  Substitution axiom. However, we know that the solution for $n^2=4$ should be $n=2$ or $-2$ ! So where did I go wrong with substitution axiom, or is there any restriction with this axiom?

Comment: The square root **function** only returns one value, namely two in this case.

Comment: $\sqrt{ }$ is **not** a function.

Comment: Interesting statement. What is $f(x)=\sqrt x$ then?

Comment: "In mathematics, a [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) is a relation between a set of inputs and a set of permissible outputs with the property that each input is related to **exactly one** output." With input $4$ the square root "computes" two possible outputs: $2$ and $-2$; thus, it is not a function, unless we adopt the convention of considering only the [principal square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root), in which case the (equality) substitution axiom fits perfectly.

Comment: Doesn't writing $f(x)=\sqrt x$, which is functional notation, means we have adopted the convention of considering only the principal square root?

Comment: @Arby - if "**we** have adopted the convention", why the OP is asking the above question ?

Comment: I believe the OP's confusion lies in the fact that he doesn't recognize that convention. He believes that the square root function returns two values leading to a problem, but in fact it returns one value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't quite yield $n = 2$; you yield $\sqrt{n^2} = 2$. That is true for both $n = 2$ and $n = -2$, just like the original equation.

The problem is that the square root function is not *quite* an inverse to the squaring function: that works only on nonnegative numbers. That is, the rule
$$
\sqrt{a^2} = a
$$
only holds for $a \geq 0$; if $a < 0$ we instead have the rule
$$
\sqrt{a^2} = -a.
$$
You can also summarize this as $\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$, in which case the substitution rule yields $|n| = 2$, again another way of saying that $n = 2$ or $n = -2$.

Comment: Oh, you perfectly address to my confuse, thank you!